# C++ dll called from Python

Tags: python, c++, dll, mfc, ctypes

I have used a C++ dll using MFC and I would like to call it from python.
This dll contains this header in the .h file

```
LONG CommOpen(BYTE port, LONG baud_rate);
```

Then I see in the free software dllexp that my function is called ?CommOpen@CFIPcmd@@QAEJEJ@Z in the binary file so no error is reported when  I do in python

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:\\Users\\toto\\FIProtocol.dll')
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_long, c_byte, c_long)
testPt = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (prototype) 
testApi = testPt (("?CommOpen@CFIPcmd@@QAEJEJ@Z", lib))
```

Until there it seems to work but then I would like  to call the in Python the equivalent in C++ of

```
Long l= CommOpen(5 ,115200);
```

But I Didn't find know how to proceed. 
Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the information presented in the question, the solution is:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(r'C:\Users\toto\FIProtocol.dll')
CommOpen = getattr(lib, "?CommOpen@CFIPcmd@@QAEJEJ@Z")
CommOpen.argtypes = [c_byte, c_long]
CommOpen.restype = c_long
```

And now it is ready to call:

```
l = CommOpen(5 ,115200)
```

Some notes:

1. Use `CDLL` rather than `WinDLL` because the function used the default `cdecl` calling convention.
2. Use `getattr` to be able to specify the mangled name.
3. It always pays to specify `argtypes` and `restype` explicitly.

---

However, it transpires that you have a much greater problem. The above was written on the basis that your function is a non-member function. Which is a reasonable assumption given that `ctypes` requires functions to be either non-member, or static.

However, when I put your managed function name into a demanger (for instance http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) it seems that the function is in fact:

```
public: long __thiscall CFIPcmd::CommOpen(unsigned char,long)
```

That is a member function of a C++ object. That cannot be accessed from `ctypes`. You'll need to create a plain C style wrapper, or find a different method of interop.

Comment: Well it seems very good! but i get >>> l = CommOpen(5 ,115200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x1D1C5504 but why?

Comment: Split the problem in two. Write a simple DLL containing a function with the same name and parameters and call it from Python. Have it call [`MessageBeep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356(v=vs.85).aspx) the N times. It it works, you DLL is probably failing because it does not find some assumption about the environment it was built to run in.

Comment: yes absolutely! So  I can't do it like this! thanks a lot   David Heffernan

Comment: So I must use another dll linked to the first one, which header contains something like extern "C" LONG __stdcall  CommOpen(BYTE port, LONG baud_rate); I already have this dll but I can't call it as the first one lib = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Users\\toto\\FIProtocolLab.dll") self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] procedure can't be found. Do you have an idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: Something like that. Although I'd expect there to be an instance of `CFIPcmd` somewhere.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean??

Comment: `CFIPcmd::CommOpen` is a member function and so is called on an instance. Presumably that is because the member function uses the instance.

Comment: @paulmarguerite: If you see `stdcall` then use `WinDLL`. You can load "FIProtocolLab.dll" in Dependency Walker to find out which function(s) can't be found from which DLL dependencies.

Comment: yes exactly, I need to load both dll in right order because FIProtocolLab.dll calls FIProtocol.dll, so now it is perfectly working!! thousands of thanks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you please improve your answer in the following way: a static member function can be called in the given way. If the function is not static, the object is prepended as 1st argument (see C++ calling convention) and thus, the function takes 3 arguments. If the function does not access the object (data, virtual functions, etc.) a dummy object `(void *)0` may work (dangerous, because off-spec). Otherwise @paul marguerite must get a pointer to a working instance of `CFIPcmd` somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my how-to sample. Strange why similar missed here.

```
import ctypes

def StrArg(pyStr = "") -> ctypes.c_char_p:
    return ctypes.c_char_p(pyStr.encode('utf-8'))

def main():
    testlib = ctypes.CDLL("../bin/Debug/MyCoolLib.dll");

    #int ProcessStr(const char*);
    pyProcessStr = testlib.ProcessStr
    pyProcessStr.restype = ctypes.c_int
    pyProcessStr.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

    nCount = pyProcessStr(StrArg("aaa,bbb,ccc"))
    print(nCount)

    # int DoWithTwoArgs(int nX, unsigned char ucY, const char* szZ);
    pyDoWithTwoArgs = testlib.DoWithTwoArgs
    pyDoWithTwoArgs.restype = ctypes.c_int
    pyDoWithTwoArgs.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_byte, ctypes.c_char_p]
    results = pyDoWithTwoArgs(100, 2, StrArg("Trololo"))
    print(results)

    print("Finsh")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The question was how to call a mangled function. Such a function cannot be accessed with `testlib.?CommOpen@CFIPcmd@@QAEJEJ@Z`.