# Trying to access C++ functions in dll using python ctypes on windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll, ctypes

I have a C++ function that accepts two parameters - void * and unsigned long * and it returns an unsigned long integer.
I tried to access this function after loading the dll and it throws an error saying:

> ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (8 bytes
>   missing) or wrong calling convention

Below is the python code for the same:

```
import ctypes

from ctypes import cdll

lib1 = cdll.LoadLibrary("Sample1.dll")

i = ctypes.c_void_p

j = ctypes.c_ulong()

lib1.Funct1.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)]

lib1.Funct1.restype = ctypes.c_ulong

res1 = lib1.Funct1(None,ctypes.byref(j))

print res1
```

Tried out various examples but did not help much...

Could anyone provide a solution to this above issue?

Thanks

Pavana

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ dll called from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184911/c-dll-called-from-python)

Comment: Can you post C++ signature of `Funct1`?

Comment: ctypes supports the `cdecl` calling convention (the caller cleans the stack) via `CDLL` and `stdcall` (the callee cleans the stack) via `WinDLL`. Try `lib1 = ctypes.WinDLL("Sample1.dll")`.

Comment: Thanks for your help eryksun. WinDLL worked and I was able to access the functions within the loaded dll!